# Symfony - entity - manyToOne orderBy

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

In documentation on Symfony (https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#orderby) I found that for sort @ManyToOne column in entity u need only add "@OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})" annotation. But It doesn't work. I think it always order by creation date.
Dies anyone find out that?:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the documentation states:

> Optional annotation that can be specified with a **@ManyToMany or @OneToMany** annotation to specify by which criteria the collection should be retrieved from the database by using an ORDER BY clause.

So the @OrderBy() annotation only applies to ManyToMany and OneToMany associations but not to ManyToOne associations. That's the reason it's not working.

Comment: Oh, I see.. I don't know why I didn't see that before:( Is there any other way to do this in ManyToOne?

Comment: Is "query_builder" in form only way to do this?:(

Comment: I guess what you need is just to add OrderBy annotation to the inverse side of the association (that means the class that has the OneToMany annotation in it), but I don't know exactly how your associations are.